# Recognize removal of Widget in Cockpit Dashboard on Cumulocity

Tags: plugins, cumulocity

Is there a way (maybe an event or something we can subscribe to) to acknowledge inside a self implemented widget, whenever this or another widget is removed from the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like an event you can subscribe to.
In the end there will always be a PUT request to update the dashboard object whenever it changes. Maybe you can utilize that.